# Is this forbidden in Java Generics?

Tags: java, generics

```
class Collator<S extends Stream<E extends Comparable<E>>> {
    S s;
    E e;

    public <S> Collator(List<S> streams){
        s = streams.get(0);
        e = s.read();
    }

    public <E> E next(){
        return e;
    }
}

interface Stream<E extends Comparable<E>>{
    public E read();
}

class Record implements Comparable<Record>{
    public Integer time;

    public int compareTo(Record r){
        return this.time.compareTo(r.time);
    }
}
```

Especially 1st line:

```
  class Collator<S extends Stream<E extends Comparable<E>>>
```

I expect to say:

> Define a collator that works on Streams of Entries where each Entry implements comparable.

Comment: Compile and run it. Does it work?

Comment: No. Obviously it did not. that is why I posted it here. But i dont know why

Comment: If it didn't compile, don't you think the error message will obviously help us help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you miss-qualified the generic parameters

```
class Collator<S extends Stream<E>,E extends Comparable<E>> {
    S s;
    E e;

    public Collator(List<S> streams){
        s = streams.get(0);
        e = s.read();
    }

    public E next(){
        return e;
    }
}

interface Stream<E extends Comparable<E>>{
    public E read();
}

class Record implements Comparable<Record>{
    public Integer time;

    public int compareTo(Record r){
        return this.time.compareTo(r.time);
    }
}
```

this compiles

in particular the line `class Collator<S extends Stream<E>,E extends Comparable<E>>` it means a Collator that works on a S that is a Stream of E and E implement Comparable

Comment: This is the way to do it, I just had the wrong? impression that E should go before S in the generic definition, I.E. `E extends Comparable<E>, S extends Stream<E>` instead of `S extends Stream<E>, E extends Comparable<E>`

Comment: @marcelo the order doesn't matter just that all used types are defined (either outside the generic definition as any other type or as one of the parameters) how else would a circular generic type be able to be defined `class CircularGeneric<B extends Back<F>,F extends Forth<B>>`

Answer (score 2):

Some glass ball guessing, since you don't show your error message:

Your constructor and method are declaring new type parameters `<E>` and `<S>` which are shadowing the type parameters of your class. Remove them.

Then, `E` should be a type parameter of your class, too.

```
class Collator<E extends Comparable<E>, S extends Stream<E>> {
    S s;
    E e;

    public Collator(List<S> streams){
        s = streams.get(0);
        e = s.read();
    }

    public E next(){
        return e;
    }
}

interface Stream<E extends Comparable<E>>{
    public E read();
}

class Record implements Comparable<Record>{
    public Integer time;

    public int compareTo(Record r){
        return this.time.compareTo(r.time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is E extends Comparable

Define a collator that works on Streams of Entries where each Entry implements comparable of a given type:

```
public class Collator<T,E extends Comparable<T>, S extends Stream<E>>
```